# Does Safari's history store IP addresses?

Tags: macos, safari, browser-history

If I visited a website by name (for instance, http://askdifferent.com), does Safari's History store the IP address of the site I visited or only the name?

If not in the browser history, is there anywhere on my Mac I can find the IP addresses visited stored/logged somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you have gone to the IP address directly in Safari and not the Fully Qualified Domain Name.

You could attempt to check the mDNSResponder cache to see what is in there for a lookup but I'm not sure how long the mDNSResponder cache lasts.

Here is a blog post about how to dump the cache to system.log before purging the cache.

http://blog.aitrus.com/2012/01/17/os-x-lion-how-to-display-dns-cache-and-purge-dns-cache/

Comment: Not long enough to help me today, but great tip!